# Manga reader with automatic downloads

Tags: gratis, reading, feed-reader

I'm looking for a Windows equivalent to the android app [MangaRock](http://www.mangarockapp.com/).

The software should be able to:

- Access manga feeds I specify manually (as can be seen [here](http://mangafox.me/manga/onepunch_man/) for example.)
- Save a list of favorites
- Display pages for convenient reading
- Check for and download new updates automatically
- Be offered at either a minimal cost or for free

As far as I know, there are plenty of options on mobile platforms, but I haven't found one on Windows.

Comment: By pc do you mean Windows?

Comment: As you used the [tag:feed-reader] tag: does it have to offer the feature to subscribe to (manga) feeds? And you want to add these feeds manually?

Comment: Just modified my question to clarify.